# Show a function is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, asymptotics, hilbert-spaces, improper-integrals

I am working on computing the resolvent set of an operator. While I have the result I need, my proof is more complex than I would like to. If the result below would be true, that would short-cut my work quite a bit.

Hopeful result: If $f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is continuous everywhere is such that $f(x)/\left(x^{1-\epsilon}\right)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $f(x)/x\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Other things I know about $f$ in case it helps:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\left(f(x)/(x^{1/2})\right)=0,{\text{ and }}f(x)\in H^1(a,\infty){\text{ for all }}a>0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. The key problem is close to the origin. For $x\in (a,\infty)$ we have

$$ \vert f(x)/x\vert = x^{-\varepsilon} \vert f(x)/x^{1-\varepsilon}\vert \leq a^{-\varepsilon} \vert f(x)/x^{1-\varepsilon}\vert, $$

thus, $f(x)/x \in L^2((a,\infty))$ for all $a>0$.

In order to see that integrability can fail under the listed conditions consider a function such that for $x\in (0,1/2)$ we have $f(x)=x^{1/2}/\vert\ln(x)\vert^{1/2}$. Then we have

$$ f(x)/x^{1-\varepsilon} = \frac{1}{x^{1/2-\varepsilon} \vert\ln(x)\vert^{1/2}} $$
which is in $L^2((0,1/2))$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Also

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x^{1/2}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{\vert\ln(x)\vert^{1/2}} =0. $$

Also we have $f(x)/x \in C^\infty((0,1/2))$, thus, $f(x)/x \in H^k((a,1/2))$ for all $a\in (0,1/2)$ and all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

However, we have with the change of variable $y=\ln(x)$

$$ \int_0^{1/2} \frac{\vert f(x)\vert^2}{x^2} dx= \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x \vert \ln(x)\vert} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-\ln(2)} \frac{1}{\vert y\vert} dy = \infty. $$

In order to make this a real counterexample, pick your favourite smooth function $\chi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_+)$ such that $\chi(x)=1$ on $(0,1/4)$ and $\chi(x)=0$ for $x\in (1/2,\infty)$ and consider $f(x)=x^{1/2} \chi(x)/\ln(x)^2$.

Comment: To elaborate on Severin's answer(+1) , we usually term those "smooth functions" as [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). See the link for an explicit example. In particular, since you are only looking for "continuous" functions, you can consider it to be identically $1$ on $(0,\frac{1}{4}]$ and then linearly join the points $(\frac{1}{4},1)$ with $(\frac{1}{3},0)$

Comment: @Severin Schraven Thank you for a complete and detailed explanation. That completely answers my question.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks for the addition (I completely forgot that those are not so easy to come by if never seen before)! I think we do need something a tiny bit better than continuous as we also want the function to be in $H^1$ ($C^1$ should do).

Comment: @Gateauaufromage You are welcome. It's a bit sad, that it is not true. It is a bit annoying as it right on the edge. If you had some properties, it might force your function to be $L^2$.

Comment: @Severin Schraven I will check if I can add some properties and, if I do so, will add it as a question and invite both you and Mr.Gandalf Sauron (nice name) to it! Thanks.

Comment: @Gateauaufromage Indeed, I like his name too, but when I told him once, he did not quite share my enthusiasm for his name :D In your position I would try to prove that $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}_+)$. In that case you should get by Hardy's inequality that $f(x)/x$ is square integrable. Apart from that I don't quite know what property one could ask for to make it true (these function spaces are trickier than we make our students believe... have been struggle with similar issues last year). In any case, good luck!

Comment: @Gateauaufromage Usually to conclude L^p convergence from a.s. convergence, one uses uniform inteegrability. i.e. for example if $\sup_{\epsilon>0}||f/x^{1-\epsilon}||_{L^{2+\delta}}<\infty$ for some $\delta>0$. But this is rather strong imo. But Steven, I don't recall a discussion with you about my name. Maybe because I have heard the compliment of "nice username" many times now(not trying to brag). My name is really a misnomer like "Random Variables" not really being random nor variables. I mean Gandalf and Sauron in the same name with profile a pic of Aragorn. That is just pure chaos.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I think I appreciate your name to this degree because I like both characters very much. Both being Maiar (if I am not mistaken, bit rusty on my LOTR lore) and standing on very different end of the good-evil spectrum. Names can have different meaning to different people (for example Steven is not listed as my name, though it is my middle name ^^). Also, I am a bit disappointed to hear that you are neither Gandalf, nor Sauron... was hoping to learn some tricks from you (teaching calculus are counts as having hobbits around. Soooo I was read to learn some magic).

Comment: Well, the only magic I do know is from Probability Theory. Outside of the realm of treacherous planes of Mathematics, I do consider myself somewhat skilled in Indian and South East Asian mythologies and religions. Who knows, someday you and I can join on a wagon ride and exchange various spells and tricks and smoke some pipe if the fool of a Took leaves us some.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I won't forget that! Maybe you can also teach me some history of mathematics. It came to my attention that Indian mathematicians developed some version of calculus very early (way before Newton-Leibniz).

Comment: Well there are many propagandist theories cropping up in India everyday. I personally don't really have any idea about it. In any case, I am mostly interested in Religious history and the cultures of South East Asian countries (like the Khmer empire, Srivijayan, Shailendra empire etc). Let us be friends, heaven knows I do need some lest I die by exploding from inside and having no one to talk to. Sorry if the last sentence became too personal.

Comment: Of all the comments above, I retained "Hardy's inequality". Although I knew of it, I had never used it. It seems like that is exactly what I need to make my work much simpler. It applies exactly to my situation where I get those formulas from applying variation of parameters to my resolvent equation. Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Let's not explode from the inside, who will smoke the pipe otherwise? :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) $\rho$ which is identially $1$ on $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ and is supported in $[-1,1]$  . Consider the restricton of $\rho$ to $(0,\infty)$. Then $\rho$ is a smooth function on $\Bbb{R}^{+}$.

Also $\|\rho\|_{\infty}\leq 1$ and $\rho$ is compactly supported, it is $L^{p}$ for all $p$.

In particular, since you only require $f$ to be continuous, you can take $\rho$ to be identically $1$ on $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and then linearly join the points $(\frac{1}{2},1)$ with $(\frac{3}{4},1)$ in $\Bbb{R}^{2}$.

Now, consider $f=\sqrt{x}\rho$ .

So notice that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{f^{2}}{x^{2(1-\epsilon)}}=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\rho^{2}x}{(x^{1-\epsilon})^{2}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x^{1-2\epsilon}}\,dx <\infty$ for all small enough $\epsilon>0$.

In the region $[\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ you will have no integrability problems as $f$ itself is compactly supported. Also, we have kept everything $\geq 0$. So showing that the integral in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ is not finite is enough.

But $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{f(x)}{x})^{2}=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\rho x}{x^{2}}=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the time you took to answer the question in a detailed way and your comment above.

Comment: @Gateauaufromage Much appreciated.